# Program that translates text using openai. The program translates the text successfully but there is more information given in the output than needed

Tags: python, translation, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am trying to translate text by using an openai in python. I am using gpt-3.5-turbo. I wrote a function to help me with the translation and it is executing and working correctly but gives me more output than I need. Here is the written function:

def translate_text(text, source_language, target_language):
prompt = f"Translate the following '{source_language}' text to '{target_language}': {text}"

```
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant that translates text."},
        {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
    ],
    max_tokens=150,
    n=1,
    stop=None,
    temperature=0.5,
)

translation = response.choices[0].message.content.strip()
return translation
```

Below I am calling the function and setting up the output:

```
    slide = presentation.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)
    shapes = slide.shapes

    answers = [row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6]]

    body_shape = shapes.placeholders[1]
    tf = body_shape.text_frame
    t0 = translate_text(answers, 'auto', 'fr').translate(answers[0])
    tf.text = "A. " + answers[0] + " <-- Translation --> " + ''.join([str(t0)])
    slide_count += 1
    print(t0)
```

My output looks like the following:

**A. Thugs of Bharat <-- Translation --> ['Thugs de Bharat', 'Pirates de l'Inde', 'Thugs de Hindostan', 'Combattants de la mer']**

How do I remove the other choices that's listed.
The desired output would be:
**A. Thugs of Bharat <-- Translation --> Thugs de Bharat**

I tried modifying the function but I have been unsuccessful. I tried modifying the return statement in the function but I also didn't have any luck trying that.

Answer (score 1):

Probably try returning a list with the first value of the previous return value you tried. Example: **previouslist = ['Thugs de Bharat', 'Pirates de l'Inde', 'Thugs de Hindostan', 'Combattants de la mer']** -> **[previouslist[0]]**.

You could try this method, but it's not a good idea to strip out the other values, and even translating with OpenAI at all. A better idea would be to use an API for translating, you can do that with the `requests` module in `python3`.